# How to create podspec file for pods with right path to Localizable assets in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode7.3, podspec

In my project I have three Pods and each have their own localizable assets under `Resources/Pod/Assets` folder. However the localizations for my main project files work but localization for pods didn't work.If I place all my pods localization assets into my main project folder , then everything works, but it is not the case I'm looking for.I need to have my pods store their own localizable assets.

Here is my podspec for my pods:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "MyPod"
  s.version          = "0.1"
  s.summary          = "A short description of MyLib."
 s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'Pod/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'MyPod' => ['Pod/**/*.{caf,xib,mp4,mp3,m4a,wav,plist,atlas}',
                             'Pod/Assets/pngs/**/*.{png,jpg}', 
                             'Pod/Assets/fr-CA.lproj/*.strings',
                             ]
  }

  s.prefix_header_file = 'MyPodPrefixHeader.pch'

  s.dependency 'MyOtherPod'

end
```

I also tried

```
      'Pod/Assets/*.{lproj}'
```

and

```
      'Pod/Assets/*.{lproj}/*.strings'
```

Everytime I change the podspec I do `pod install`
But none of them worked. Pod localizable assets are not loading in my project.

ANy ideas where I could have gone wrong ?